# Need help choosing resistors for difference amplifier

Tags: operational-amplifier, resistors, feedback

In the circuit below I am trying to achieve 15.56 gain on IC2.

[image]

The following combinations (in kOhms) are fairly close:

20/1.3 or 200/13 = 15.38
47/3 or 470/30 = 15.67
51/3.3 or 510/33 = 15.45
56/3.6 or 560/36 = 15.56

The pair 56k/3.6k is actually spot-on and seems to be OK for [OPA548](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/opa548.pdf) and required bandwidth (under 200kHz) per [this answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/173733/187920). Although it is rather on low side, just as 560k/36k seems a bit too high.

Now, to consider [SI8920B](https://www.silabs.com/documents/public/data-sheets/si8920-datasheet.pdf) requirements I have to look at input impedance of difference amplifier, or maybe at all three impedances according to [this answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/191490/187920).

The problem is that I don't understand which one is specified in the datasheet. It says "Output Resistive Load" minimum is 5k. If this is differential impedance then all combinations but 20/1.3 are OK. However an application example in the datasheet has 5k resistor on both lines. If this means datasheet specification is for individual outputs then I am left with high resistance combinations only.

So, my gut feeling tells me to go with 200k/13k.

Question: is this a right choice?

Comment: Thanks! I take it, you interpret datasheet as differential impedance then. I've found some suitable 0.01% arrays with 0.005% matching, although quite expensive. Will probably go with discrete to save money.

Comment: I posted my comment as an answer, per EE.SE rules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

56K/3.6K 0.1% are valid values. Avoid trim pots as they have a high thermal drift and can affect common mode DC errors.

For several $USD each you can get 0.025% to 0.001% tolerance resistors that are ultra-stable, made by Caddock. Matched pairs can be had for lots of money. It's your call.